# How to properly use dictionary collection?

Tags: swift, dictionary

Here is my code:

```
class className: Codable {
    let comments: [String: String, String:String]
}
```

I am getting the following errors:

> Expected ']' in dictionary type
>
> Expected declaration
>
> Consecutive declarations on a line muse be separated by ';'

From [Swift docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105) it is done this way (I think):

```
let comments: [String: String]
```

But for me it won't work because my `comments` in `mongoose.Schema` is defined as below (in the server):

```
comments: [{
    identifier: String,
    text: String
}]
```

I defined comments collection to push it to the server for testing as below (it worked):

```
var comments = ["identifier" : "SomeRandomText", "text": "SomeRandomText"]
```

Now my question is, how can I define the `comments` in my class that extends `Codable` to match my `comments` in the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let comments: [String: String]` is the correct way.

You want a Dictionary, whose keys are `String`s and whose values are also `String`s and that's what the above line declares.

If you check the type of your `comments` variable when declaring it with initial values (option click on the variable name), you'll see that its type is `[String:String]`, which is just a shorthand notation for `Dictionary<String,String>`.

```
var comments = ["identifier" : "SomeRandomText", "text": "SomeRandomText"] //Here comments is of type [String:String]
```

Comment: Thanks your right, I checked and it was of type [String:String] but when I use it as that, it doesn't return anything from the server

Comment: Then you need to clarify your question. You say that when you declare your variable with initial values, it works fine. However, when looking at your `mongoose.Schema` declaration, that looks like an _array of dictionaries_, so based on that the type of `comments` should be `[[String:String]]`, which is shorthand for `Array<Dictionary<String,String>>`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be an array of documents, so probably something like this should work:

```
class className: Codable {
    let comments: [{String: String, String:String}]
}
```

And the collection for testing the same:

```
var comments = [{"identifier" : "SomeRandomText", "text": "SomeRandomText"}]
```

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking in then Node.js part

Comment: The code shown in the question is clearly Swift code. AFAIK `Codable` doens't even exist in node.

Comment: My fault, I'm sorry